# Trying to add Dropdown to menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a dropdown to a template i downloaded, but i'm not the greatest with CSS when it comes to existing templates.

**HTML Code:**

```
    <header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="index.html">KB Customs</a></h1>
      <div class="fright">
      <div class="indent"> <span class="address">MI 49544</span> <span class="phone">Tel: 174</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="maintenance.html">Products </a></li>

          <!-- Insert 5 drop downs here ------------------------->

        <li><a href="repair.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="price.html">FAQ & Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="locations.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="items">
          <li> <img src="images/slider-img1.jpg" alt="" /> </li>
          <li> <img src="images/slider-img2.jpg" alt="" /> </li>
          <li> <img src="images/slider-img3.jpg" alt="" /> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="prev" href="#">prev</a> <a class="next" href="#">next</a> </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS that is currently there:**

```
/***** menu *****/
header nav {
width:100%;
height:52px;
background:url(../images/menu-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
}

#page1 header nav {
margin-bottom:28px;
}

.menu li {
float:left;
position:relative;
background:url(../images/menu-spacer.gif) left top no-repeat;
}

.menu > li:first-child {
background:none;
}

.menu li a {
display:inline-block;
font-size:18px;
line-height:25px;
padding:12px 28px 12px 29px;
color:#808080;
text-transform:capitalize;
}

 .menu > li:first-child > a {
text-indent:-999em;
background:url(../images/menu-home.png) center -25px no-repeat;
min-width:22px;
}

 .menu li a.active, .menu > li > a:hover {
color:#fff;
}

 .menu > li:first-child > a.active, .menu > li:first-child > a:hover {
background-position:center 15px;
 }
```

My main issue with css like this is that i don't know the difference between # and . also what > does.

Sorry if i sound like a noob, been away from CSS for a while.

**EDIT:** I appreciate the explanation of what all that means, but can someone help me in achieving my goal? :)

Comment: unfortunately i don't have one...i tried to implement my website live...but my router isn't letting me forward ports

Comment: @user1574685, u are making a menu with dropdown functionality ?

Comment: Its currently a normal menu, i would like to turn one of the selections into a dropdown selection.  I got this from a template and would like to add to it

Answer (score 2):

Let me take each one individually:

- `#`: selects elements by their `id`. For example, `#myElement` will select this div:

  ```
  <div id="myElement"></div>
  ```

  IDs are exclusive on a page, so it will only style the first element with that ID.
- `.`: selects all elements with the given class. For example `.myClass` will select all of the following elements.

  ```
  <div class="myClass">
     <h1 class="myClass">Header</p>
     <p class="myClass">Text</p>
  </div>
  ```
- `>` selects a direct child of the selector on the left. For example, this selector: `.myClass > .mySubClass` will select the `div` with text "Foo" but not the ones with text of "Bar" or "Baz":

  ```
  <div class="myClass">
      <div class="mySubClass">Foo</div>
      <div class="notMySubClass">
          <div class="mySubClass">Bar</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySubClass">Baz</div>
  ```

**Answer to Question from Comments:**

**Q:** What does `.menu ul ul ul` mean?

**A:** anywhere you see a space in CSS, that means "descendant of". In the (updated) example above for `.myClass > .mySubClass`, if I had used `.myClass .mySubClass` instead, it would have selected the `div` with text "Foo" and the `div` with text "Bar". Even though the `div` with "Bar" isn't a direct descendant of the `div` with `class="myClass"`.

`.menu ul ul ul` would select all of the `ul`s in the next example that I have noted with a comment:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul> <!-- will be selected -->
                        <li>Foo</li>
                        <li>Bar</li>
                        <li>
                            <ul> <!-- will be selected -->
                                <li>Foo</li>
                            </ul
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul> <!-- will be selected -->
                        <li>Foo</li>
                        <li>Bar</li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What about when you have something like this: .menu ul ul ul

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not very difficult to understand. Just start reading tutorials or from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).
Just for a start:

- `#, ., >` etc are all called Selectors. 
  CSS selectors allow you to select and manipulate HTML elements. '#' refers to an id of any HTML element which is generally unique, Ex: `page1` in your example.
  . refers to the class attribute.
- The class selector selects elements with a specific class attribute. Many elements can have the same class name and so they can all have the same styles. Example: `.menu` refers to a class name.
- `>` refers to the direct descendant selector i.e. any element which is direct descendant of any other element. Example `.menu > li`. In this case all the direct `li` children of `.menu` parent will have the style specified.
- `:first-child, :last-child` etc are called pseudo-class selectors and provide additional options for targeting a particular element. Example in your case: `.menu > li:first-child` will refer to the `first li child of menu class`.